# Executing a TCL script from line N

Tags: shell, tcl

I have a TCL script that say, has 30 lines of automation code which I am executing in the dc shell (Synopsys Design Compiler). I want to stop and exit the script at line 10, exit the dc shell and bring it back up again after performing a manual review. However, this time, I want to run the script starting from line number 11, without having to execute the first 10 lines.

Instead of having two scripts, one which contains code till line number 10 and the other having the rest, I would like to make use of only one script and try to execute it from, let's say, line number N.

Something like: 
    `source a.tcl -line 11`

How can I do this?

Comment: I'd look into `trace`: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.htm For example, set an enterstep-trace that stubs the command about to be executed until the eleventh command, then remove self.

Comment: This isn't a core feature of Tcl, and probably won't ever become one. You don't need it either…

Answer (score 1):

If you have Tcl 8.6+ and if you consider re-modelling your script on top of a [Tcl coroutine](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/coroutine.htm), you can realise this continuation behaviour in a few lines. This assumes that you run the script from an interactive Tcl shell (dc shell?).

```
# script.tcl
if {[info procs allSteps] eq ""} {
    # We are not re-entering (continuing), so start all over.
    proc allSteps {args} {
      yield; # do not run when defining the coroutine;
      puts 1
      puts 2
      puts 3
      yield; # step out, once first sequence of steps (1-10) has been executed
      puts 4
      puts 5
      puts 6
      rename allSteps ""; # self-clean, once the remainder of steps (11-N) have run
    }
    coroutine nextSteps allSteps
}

nextSteps; # run coroutine
```

1. Pack your script into a proc body (`allSteps`).
2. Within the proc body: Place a `yield` to indicate the hold/ continuation point after your first steps (e.g., after the 10th step).
3. Create a coroutine `nextSteps` based on `allSteps`.
4. Protect the `proc` and `coroutine` definitions in a way that they do not cause a re-definition (when steps are pending)

Then, start your interactive shell and run `source script.tcl`:

```
% source script.tcl
1
2
3
```

Now, perform your manual review. Then, continue from within the same shell:

```
% source script.tcl
4
5
6
```

Note that you can run the overall 2-phased sequence any number of times (because of the self-cleanup of the coroutine proc: `rename`):

```
% source script.tcl
1
2
3
% source script.tcl
4
5
6
```

Again: All this assumes that you do *not* exit from the shell, and maintain your shell while performing your review. If you need to exit from the shell, for whatever reason (or you cannot run Tcl 8.6+), then Donal's suggestion is the way to go.

### Update

If applicable in your case, you may improve the implementation by using an [anonymous (lambda) proc](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/apply.htm). This simplifies the lifecycle management (avoiding re-definition, managing coroutine and proc, no need for a `rename`):

```
# script.tcl
if {[info commands nextSteps] eq ""} {
    # We are not re-entering (continuing), so start all over.
    coroutine nextSteps apply {args {
      yield; # do not run when defining the coroutine;
      puts 1
      puts 2
      puts 3
      yield; # step out, once first sequence of steps (1-10) has been executed
      puts 4
      puts 5
      puts 6
    }}
}

nextSteps
```

Comment: The restriction of persisting the shell can be obviously relaxed when using some terminal session multiplexer (tmux, screen).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to open the text file, parse it to get the first *N* commands (`info complete` is useful there), and then evaluate those (or the rest of the script). Doing this efficiently produces slightly different code when you're dropping the tail as opposed to when you're dropping the prefix.

```
proc ReadAllLines {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set lines {}
    # A little bit careful in case you're working with very large scripts
    while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
        lappend lines $line
    }
    close $f
    return $lines
}

proc SourceFirstN {filename n} {
    set lines [ReadAllLines $filename]
    set i 0
    set script {}
    foreach line $lines {
        append script $line "\n"
        if {[info complete $script] && [incr i] >= $n} {
            break              
        }
    }
    info script $filename
    unset lines
    uplevel 1 $script
}

proc SourceTailN {filename n} {
    set lines [ReadAllLines $filename]
    set i 0
    set script {}
    for {set j 0} {$j < [llength $lines]} {incr j} {
        set line [lindex $lines $j]
        append script $line "\n"
        if {[info complete $script]} {
            if {[incr i] >= $n} {
                info script $filename
                set realScript [join [lrange $lines [incr j] end] "\n"]
                unset lines script
                return [uplevel 1 $realScript]
            }
            # Dump the prefix we don't need any more
            set script {}
        }
    }
    # If we get here, the script had fewer than n lines so there's nothing to do
}
```

Be aware that the kinds of files you're dealing with can get pretty large, and Tcl currently has some hard memory limits. On the other hand, if you can `source` the file at all, you're already within that limit…

Comment: I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Also, on a sidenote, shouldn't this be a feature that everybody can make use of ?

Comment: @batssassin Evidence in reality suggests that almost nobody wants it; you're the first to ask that I can think of.